# Monitor Java Hibernate data retreival

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Say I have a JPA like

```
SELECT x FROM Person
```

Now, I would like to monitor Hibernate's progress while it loads the data from database, so that I can display a progress bar to user. Is such thing possible? I know I can display **indeterminate** progress bar, but what about displaying a **determinate** progress bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK that's not really possible since you can't get that the state of the database query (how many rows are already loaded etc.) and thus you'd have to wait for this to complete.

Hibernate would then create the entities from the results and although you might intercept here I doubt Hibernate provides some useful hooks.

So all you *might* be able to tell might be when Hibernate has finished loading the results from the database and when it created/updated all the necessary entities.

Alternatively, you could try and load the entities in batches, i.e. first get the number of results and then load individual chunks (e.g. 0-99, 100-199, ...). Since you know the number of results you can calculate the number of chunks and in between the chunks you could update the progress bar. Note, however, that this would decrease performance, especially if the query is quite complex.